# Send email does not printing query result in csv

Tags: sql, sql-server, email

I'm using following code to send an attachment in email in CSV format, this is working fine but when i try to use the original query i-e `select col1, col2, col3 .. from DBTable` in place of test query `select ''1'', ''2'', ''3'', ''4''` email is not being sent, even there is not any error but email not being sent, stored procedure get executed in the same way with both queries.

```
EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='Notificatins and Alerts',
    @recipients = @EmailRecipient,
    @subject = @MessageSubject,
    @body = @MessageBody,
    @body_format = 'HTML',
    @query='SET NOCOUNT ON;
            select ''sep=,''            
            select ''1'', ''2'', ''3'', ''4''  ',
--select ''1'', ''2'', ''3'', ''4'' 
    @attach_query_result_as_file=1,
    @query_attachment_filename = 'Results.csv',
    @query_result_separator =',',
    @query_result_no_padding=1, --trim
    --@query_result_width=32767,  --stop wordwrap
    @exclude_query_output =1,
    @append_query_error = 0,
    @query_result_header =0;
```

can any one help me on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. Hope this will help someone:

```
EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='Notificatins and Alerts',
    @recipients = @EmailRecipient,
    @subject = @MessageSubject,
    @body = @MessageBody,
    @body_format = 'HTML',
    @query='SET NOCOUNT ON;
            select ''sep=,''            
            select col1, col2, col3 .. from dbName.dbo.DBTable  ',
--select ''1'', ''2'', ''3'', ''4'' 
    @attach_query_result_as_file=1,
    @query_attachment_filename = 'Results.csv',
    @query_result_separator =',',
    @query_result_no_padding=1, --trim
    --@query_result_width=32767,  --stop wordwrap
    @exclude_query_output =1,
    @append_query_error = 0,
    @query_result_header =0;
```

simply one have to use DBName.dbo with table name that was missing in my query.